# How can I create a REPL for Mathematica in Sublime Text

Tags: kernel, interface, command-line, user-interface

I would like to be able to interact with *Mathematica command line interface from within Sublime Text*.

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) has a package called [Sublime REPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) that provides an interface for different programming environments interactively. Unfortunately Mathematica is not one of them and I started to see if I can tweak the package and add Mathematica REPL too.

The general way to proceed is to call the program we want to interact with through a command and the rest is mostly taken care of by the REPL package. For example to call R REPL, the package runs 

`"cmd": ["Rterm.exe", "--ess", "--encoding=$win_cmd_encoding"]`

or for Matlab it is 

`"cmd": ["matlab", "-nodesktop","-nosplash"]`

Now I know that the command line interface of mma is `wolfram.exe` which I added to my path and it works from the `cmd` or `powershell` but I am not able to get it to work from within sublime.

**What worked though is to do it indirectly through a system shell** by which I mean to open either `shell` or `powershell` repls and from there type `wolfram` and then I can have a repl but not directly.

My question is whether there is special switch or argument that I need to pass that I am not aware of? Or is it a fundamental issue going on here that I am not aware of?

I make this disclaimer here that I am not a programmer and a newbie in mathematica so I might have not been aware of relevant keywords in my previous searches for similar questions or possible solutions.
I looked at two implementation of a repl for Mathematica (mathematica mode for emacs and a [REPL for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7624-mathematica-repl)) to see how they do it but I could not figure it out in the end.

Comment: http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/05/17/wolframscript-run-your-code-from-anywhere/

Comment: Thanks @Alan for the reference. I had seen this but the article is referring to a REPL provided by mathematica and does not give much info how to access it from other apps. Also I am using Mma 10, do you happen to know whether there is a significant difference in the functionality of CLI between the two version?